# invalid method declaration ; return type required

Tags: android

Have errors with this core for some reason please help me understand. I think I missed something.
it says invalid method declaration; return type required.

That is AlertFragment

```
package com.suqareapps.Shopping_Cart;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class AlertFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView.View(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Creating view corresponding to the fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_fragment, container, false);

    return v;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

just override `public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle)` not `public View onCreateView.View`. Because there isn't a method like `public View onCreateView.View` in `Fragment` class.

Comment: on other words: change method name from **onCreateView.View** to **onCreateView**.